# Wpf application loading very slowly

Tags: c#, wpf

I have developed wpf application which calls a lot of processes and windows services , but it takes forever to start . I am trying to debug the application everything seems to be working fine .Therefore, i don't understand why the window does not show up . I would like to post the code but it's too long and i don't understand in which particular area the problem is .

Comment: Since we can not see what is going on, try commenting out parts of your applications startup code to see if you can find the bottleneck or use a profiler like [Red Gates Ants Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, without seeing the code, you will need to do some code profiling. [Here is a good article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288073.aspx) that talks about tricks and tools for profiling your code